# Correctly handle errors using watchdog

Tags: python, exception, watchdog

I'm trying to understand how to use the error handling correct in Python. 
I'm usting Watchdog to look in my folers in a network connected disc. Somethimes the disc dissconnects shortly and then connects again and an error pops up. "Exception in thread Thread-2:"

I have an error handeler but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly.

Should I put an other try at the observer.schedule step?

Python 3.6, Windows 10

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "P:\\03_auto\\Indata"
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Comment: The Excpetion raises inside the thread, you'll need to handle errors in there, presumably in the `start()` method.

Comment: Thanks.

So if I do this:

try:
    observer.start()
except:
    print('Det har blivit något fel')
If except come to play, my script will stop? Do I have to make som kind of loop so it will keep on scanning? Or does Watchdog take care of that?

Comment: Oh, `Observer` is part of a third-party package. I was not aware. That makes it a bit more difficult. Handling exceptions around `observer.start()` won't help as the exception comes from another thread and thus is on another stack. Possible solutions might be subclassing `Observer` to extend its exception handling or overwriting `sys.excepthook`. I'll fiddle around with approaches and outline them in an answer. Might take a bit though, it's about lunch time :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `sys.excepthook` approach I mentioned in my comment is not feasible at the moment. There's a more than a decade old [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue1230540) that makes threads derived from `threading.Thread` ignore `sys.excepthook`. There are some workarounds outlined in the message thread of that bug, but I am hestiant to post an answer employing a workaround, especially since this bug finally seems to get a fix for Python 3.8.

The other option would be to derive a custom Observer from Watchdog's Observer.
The most basic way I can think of is a wrapper around the parent's `run()` method:

```
class CustomObserver(Observer):

    def run(self):
        while self.should_keep_running():
            try:
                # Tweak the super call if you require compatibility with Python 2
                super().run()
            except OSError: 
            # You did not mention the excpetion class in your post.
            # Be specific about what you want to handle here
                # give the file system some time to recover
                time.sleep(.5)
```

Judging by a quick glance at the source, all Observers seem to be inheriting their `run` from [`EventDispatcher.run()`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/blob/master/src/watchdog/observers/api.py?#L196), so you probably could even omit the wrapper and reimplement that method directly

```
class CustomObserver(Observer):

    def run(self):
        while self.should_keep_running():
            try:
                self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
            except queue.Empty:
                continue
            except OSError:
                time.sleep(.5)
```

However, I don't have that package installed on my box, so these things are untested; you might have to fiddle around a bit to get this going.
Oh, and make sure to replace the `OSError`* by whatever exception class actually raises in your case :)

**Edit:**
* As per @HenryYik's comment below, a network drive disconnecting, appears to be raising an `OSError` (WinError 64: ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED) on Windows systems. I find it likely that UNIX style OSs raise the same type of exception in that situation, hence I updated the code snippets to now use `OSError` instead of the `FileNotFoundError` I used originally.

Comment: Just for reference, i was in a similar situation as OP and received an OSError (WinError 64) when my network drive got disconnected for some time.

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you! I have added that information to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried your solution and still get the OSError WinError64 when my network drive disconnects. Seems not catching the error at the correct place

Comment: @HenryYik I could only go by assumption here. The OP's post neither states what exception raises, nor where exactly in the code it does so. Your comments unfortunately also do not really help to pinpoint the exact source of the issue. Please create a question with an MCVE and the full traceback for peope to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

I think `super().run()` is not a good answer.
I've tried many things with shmee's answer, but it was not concrete and meaningless.

Below is my answer.
I've finished the test.

```py
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler


class Watcher :
    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()
        print('observer init...')

    def run(self):
        global osv_status
        try :            
            event_handler = MyHandler(patterns=["*.txt"])
            self.observer.schedule(event_handler, Directory, recursive=True)
            self.observer.start()
            osv_status = 1            

        except OSError as ex:
            print("OSError")
            time.sleep(.5)

            if self.observer.is_alive() is True:
                self.observer.stop()
                self.observer.join()
                print("Observer is removed [ ",osv_status," ]")
                osv_status = 2

        except Exception as ex:
            self.logger.exception("Exception ex :{0} ".format(ex))


class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("MyHandler Init")

    def on_created(self, event): 
        print('New file is created ',event.src_path)

        except Exception as ex:            
            self.logger.exception("Exception ex :{0} ".format(ex))


    def on_modified(self,event):
        print('File is modified ',event.src_path)
        try :
            doing()
        except Exception as ex:            
            self.logger.exception("Exception ex :{0} ".format(ex))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    .....
    osv_status = 0 # 0: ready, 1:start  2: halt
    wch =Watcher()
    wch.run()

    try :
        while(1):
            if is_Connect == False:
                sock_connect()
                print('sock_connect')

            time.sleep(1)
            if os.path.exists(Directory) is False and osv_status == 1:
                wch.observer.stop()
                wch.observer.join()
                print("Observer is removed [ ",osv_status," ]")
                osv_status = 0
            elif os.path.exists(Directory) is True and (osv_status == 0 or osv_status == 2):
                if wch.observer.is_alive() is False:
                    wch =Watcher()
                    wch.run()
```

Comment: This important concept is removing observer.
When Observer is alive, another observer relaunching make halt
So we should manage observer status.

Answer (score 0):

I've also posted this in a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56543182/10069983)

This is how i solved this problem:

```
    from watchdog import observers
    from watchdog.observers.api import DEFAULT_OBSERVER_TIMEOUT, BaseObserver


    class MyEmitter(observers.read_directory_changes.WindowsApiEmitter):
        def queue_events(self, timeout):
            try:
                super().queue_events(timeout)
            except OSError as e:
                print(e)
                connected = False
                while not connected:
                    try:
                        self.on_thread_start()  # need to re-set the directory handle.
                        connected = True
                        print('reconnected')
                    except OSError:
                        print('attempting to reconnect...')
                        time.sleep(10)


    observer = BaseObserver(emitter_class=MyEmitter, timeout=DEFAULT_OBSERVER_TIMEOUT)
    ...
```

Subclassing `WindowsApiEmitter` to catch the exception in `queue_events`. In order to continue after reconnecting, watchdog needs to re-set the directory handle, which we can do with `self.on_thread_start()`.

Then use `MyEmitter` with `BaseObserver`, we can now handle losing and regaining connection to shared drives.